# Bulkify Apex Trigger that searches LongText for words

Tags: apex, trigger, bulk-api

I have a trigger that checks a longtext field on the account for about 60 different words. It works fine on a few, but when I do a mass-update, it fails.

What can I do to fix this?

Below is my code... I've abbreviated the rest of the if statements because they are all the same, just searching for another word and updating the corresponding field.

```
trigger acctGrade on Account (before update, before insert)
{
  if(Trigger.isBefore) 
  {
    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)
     {
       for(Account a:trigger.new)
      {
        if(a.Field1__c.contains('Word'))
          a.Word_Score__c = 100;
        if(a.Field1__c.contains('Alphabet'))
          a.Alphabet_Score__c = 3;
        if(a.Field1__c.contains('Sesame'))
          a.Sesame_Score__c = 3;
        if(a.Field1.contains('Place'))
          a.Place_Score__c = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Holy crap that formatting is rough to read.  You might want to fix that....

Comment: How does it "fail"?

Comment: Do you have a test class for this and does it give 100% coverage for the `if` statement lines? I have to wonder if there isn't one where the syntax might be slightly "off" or else where the field isn't being set with a valid integer value and you're only catching it when there's a mass update because that's the only time when that statement actually returns a value?

Comment: Are you looking in one text field or sixty? Your description doesn't match the code. And depending on the answer, there are different solutions.

Comment: At a superficial level everything looks good, not much we can do without details about what is failing ...

Comment: n.b. a trigger on Account that is (before update, before insert) can omit the tests for `Trigger.isBefore` and `if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)` - I'll bet the issue here is some `a.fieldX__c` value is null in your batch and the contains() method fails with an attempt to de-reference null object. Unless you are sure `a.fieldX__c` can't be null, you need to rewrite each `if` as 'if (a.fieldX__c != null && a.fieldX__c.contains('somestring'))

Comment: My test class has 100% coverage because I put values in field1__c to make every IF statement true. This is the error                  acctGrade: execution of BeforeUpdate

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Trigger.acctGrade: line 10, column 1

Comment: There's your issue. You have a null value in there. As a null check that contains all of your contains checks. That will cause it to bail early.

Comment: possible duplicate of [General trigger bulkification - best practices](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another pattern you might consider that has the advantage of "resetting" the scores when a word is removed:

```
trigger acctGrade on Account (before insert, before update) {
   for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
       String s = a.Field1__c;
       if (s == null) s = '';
       a.Word_Score__c = s.contains('Word') ? 100 : 0;
       a.Alphabet_Score__c = s.contains('Alphabet') ? 3 : 0;
       a.Place_Score__c = contains('Place') ? 1 : 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Really nice pattern.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the null pointer solution (as others have suggested) you simply need to check for a null value first:

```
trigger acctGrade on Account (before update, before insert)
{
  if(Trigger.isBefore) 
  {
    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
       for(Account a:trigger.new)
       {
          if(a.Field1__c != null && !String.isBlank(a.Field1__c))
          {
              if(a.Field1__c.contains('Word'))
                a.Word_Score__c = 100;
              if(a.Field1__c.contains('Alphabet'))
                a.Alphabet_Score__c = 3;
              if(a.Field1__c.contains('Sesame'))
                a.Sesame_Score__c = 3;
              if(a.Field1.contains('Place'))
                a.Place_Score__c = 1;
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to further improve performance, you could use String.isBlank(a.Field1__c), to avoid blank or whitespace only fields too.

Comment: For some reason, it still fails on bulk account updates with  System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object. The line causing it is the first if(a.field1__c.contains statement.

Comment: In your code please add a debug statement before that line to output the value of a and a.Field1__c. Also notice the edit I have made as I had not put the "not" symbol in before the suggestion around the String.isBlank method. I have also made it an and statement.